# How do I compare two collections in Jest ignoring element order?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

When writing a unit test in Jest, how can I test that an array contains exactly the expected values *in any order*?

*In Chai*, I can write:

```
const value = [1, 2, 3];
expect(value).to.have.members([2, 1, 3]);
```

What's the equivalent syntax in Jest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an Array equality match function that ignores element position in jest.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40135684/1048572)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an Array equality match function that ignores element position in jest.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135684/is-there-an-array-equality-match-function-that-ignores-element-position-in-jest)

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to use the custom matcher `.toIncludeSameMembers()` from [jest-community/jest-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-extended#toincludesamemembersmembers).

Example given from the README

```js
test('passes when arrays match in a different order', () => {
    expect([1, 2, 3]).toIncludeSameMembers([3, 1, 2]);
    expect([{ foo: 'bar' }, { baz: 'qux' }]).toIncludeSameMembers([{ baz: 'qux' }, { foo: 'bar' }]);
});
```

It might not make sense to import a library just for one matcher but they have a lot of other useful matchers I've find useful.

Additional note, if you're using Typescript, you [should import](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#typescript) the types for the methods added to `expect` with this line:

```
import 'jest-extended';
```

Answer (score 3):

I would probably just check that the arrays were equal when sorted:

```
expect(value.sort()).toEqual([2, 1, 3].sort())
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [`arrayContaining`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectarraycontainingarray)

```
expect(value).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([2, 1, 3]));
```

Comment: `arrayContaining` is similar to what I need. However, `arrayContaining` allows `actual` to have additional values that are not in `expected`. I want to make sure that both arrays contain *exactly the same elements*, only potentially in different orders.

Comment: Then you have write it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the `array.sort` method to line up the order in conjunction with the `arrayContaining` method. You might also include a length test for good measure.

```
const value = [1, 2, 3];
expect(value).toHaveLength(3);
expect(value.sort()).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(value.sort()));
```

Comment: Your second expect tests that value contains its own items. If you're sorting the lists, surely you don't need to also use `arrayContaining`?

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the answer by [spoonmeiser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577190/spoonmeiser) that uses the copying version of sort, [toSorted()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted).

```
expect(value.toSorted((a, b) => a - b)).toEqual([1, 2, 3])
```