# Jest compare arrays WITH ORDER

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Everything which I've searched is always without/ignoring order.
I want to compare 2 arrays with order.

```
expect([1, 2, 3].concat(4)).toEqualWithOrder([1, 2, 3, 4])

expect([{ value: 1}, { value: 2}, { value: 3 }].concat({ value: 4 })
.toEqualWithOrder([
  { value: 1 },
  { value: 2 },
  { value: 3 },
  { value: 4 },
])
```

How can I do that with Jest? Should we use `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the normal `.toEqual` method. It does require the items to appear in the same order.

Only to [deviate from that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40135684/1048572) you'd need a special method.